# Jquery function doesn't work on the second time

Tags: jquery, css

I have expander gallery with slider inside and external page. I want tou use two gallery on one page. First one working perfectly but second one doesn't work. It looks like something missing but I do not know what it is.

```
<!-- FIRST -->
<div class="portfolio-top"></div>          


    <!-- Portfolio Plus Filters -->
    <div class="portfolio">
    <!-- Portfolio Wrap -->  
    <div id="portfolio-wrap">

        <!-- Portfolio Item FullScreen Expander -->                   
        <div class="portfolio-item one-four uclu one_third">

        <div class="portfolio-image">
            <img src="ekipman/studyo-1.jpg" alt="Stüdyo"/>
        </div>

        <div class="project-overlay">
            <div class="open-project-link">
                <a class="open-project" href="studyo.html" title="Göster"></a>             
            </div>
            <div class="project-info">
                <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
                <h4 class="project-name">Stüdyo</h4>
                <p class="project-categories">Atölye Stüdyo</p> 
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Portfolio Item FullScreen Expander -->



   </div>
   <!--/Portfolio Wrap -->

    </div>
    <!--/Portfolio Plus Filters -->





    <div class="portfolio-bottom"></div>

    <!-- Project Page Holder-->
    <div id="project-page-holder">

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="project-page-data"></div>

    </div>
    <!--/FIRST-->



    <!-- SECOND -->
<div class="portfolio-top"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).load(function() {

// Project Page Expander

(function(){

      var container = $( "#project-page-holder" );
      var $items = $('#portfolio-wrap .open-project-link');
      index = $items.length;
      $('#portfolio-wrap .open-project-link').click(function(){

      if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
      } else 
      { lastIndex = index;
      index = $(this).index();
      $items.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var myUrl = $(this).find('.open-project').attr("href") + " .item-data"; 





      $('#project-page-data').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){



            $("#project-page-data").load(myUrl,function(e){  
                var $helper = $('.helper');
                var height = $helper.height();


                    $('#project-page-data').css("min-height", height);

                    $('.project-slider').css({'height' : ''});  
                    $('#maximage').css({'height' : ''});    



                        $('#maximage').maximage({
                            cycleOptions: {
                                fx: 'fade',
                                speed: 1000, // Has to match the speed for CSS transitions in jQuery.maximage.css (lines 30 - 33)
                                timeout: 6000,
                                prev: '#arrow_left',
                                next: '#arrow_right',
                                pause: 1,
                            },
                        });






            });

            $('#project-page-data').delay(400).animate({opacity:1}, 400);

      });


      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-bottom").offset().top -40}, 900);


      //Project Page Open



          $('#project-page-holder').slideUp(600, function(){

              $('#project-page-data').css('visibility', 'visible');}).delay(1100).slideDown(1000,function(){                  

                    $('#project-page-data').fadeIn('slow',function(){initBxModal();});
                    $('.element_fade_in').each(function () {
                        $(this).appear(function() {
                          $(this).delay(100).animate({opacity:1,right:"0px"},1000);
                        }); 
                    });

              });


      }

      return false;       

      });

      //Project Page Close

      $(document).on('click', '#project_close', function(event) {


      $('#project-page-data').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){      

            $('#project-page-holder').delay(400).slideUp(400);

      });

            $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-top").offset().top - 70}, 800);
            $items.removeClass('active') ;

            return false;

      });

})(); });



   $(window).load(function() {

// Project Page Expander

(function(){

      var container = $( "#project-page-holder2" );
      var $items = $('#portfolio-wrap2 .open-project-link2');
      index = $items.length;
      $('#portfolio-wrap2 .open-project-link2').click(function(){

      if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
      } else 
      { lastIndex = index;
      index = $(this).index();
      $items.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var myUrl = $(this).find('.open-project2').attr("href") + " .item-data"; 





      $('#project-page-data2').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){



            $("#project-page-data2").load(myUrl,function(e){  
                var $helper = $('.helper');
                var height = $helper.height();


                    $('#project-page-data2').css("min-height", height);

                    $('.project-slider').css({'height' : ''});  
                    $('#maximage2').css({'height' : ''});   



                        $('#maximage2').maximage({
                            cycleOptions: {
                                fx: 'fade',
                                speed: 1000, // Has to match the speed for CSS transitions in jQuery.maximage.css (lines 30 - 33)
                                timeout: 6000,
                                prev: '#arrow_left',
                                next: '#arrow_right',
                                pause: 1,
                            },
                        });






            });

            $('#project-page-data2').delay(400).animate({opacity:1}, 400);

      });


      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-bottom").offset().top -40}, 900);


      //Project Page Open



          $('#project-page-holder2').slideUp(600, function(){

              $('#project-page-data2').css('visibility', 'visible');}).delay(1100).slideDown(1000,function(){                 

                    $('#project-page-data2').fadeIn('slow',function(){initBxModal();});
                    $('.element_fade_in').each(function () {
                        $(this).appear(function() {
                          $(this).delay(100).animate({opacity:1,right:"0px"},1000);
                        }); 
                    });

              });


      }

      return false;       

      });

      //Project Page Close

      $(document).on('click', '#project_close', function(event) {


      $('#project-page-data2').animate({opacity:0}, 400,function(){     

            $('#project-page-holder2').delay(400).slideUp(400);

      });

            $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop: $(".portfolio-top").offset().top - 70}, 800);
            $items.removeClass('active') ;

            return false;

      });

})(); });
```

The problem is when i click the second one it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could describe difference between each function?! And "it doesn't work" doesn't mean anything, be more precise please

Comment: For dynamically added controls use [event-delgation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). That's best I understood from the long code

Comment: So in fact you have only one function??? At least check your console for error

Comment: @A.Wolff i've already check my console. there is no error.

Comment: at line number 48, 49, 160 and 161 in you js, remove comma (,)

Comment: thanks mate but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing `$(window).load(function() {});` and put your javscript inside `function pageLoad()` in html/presentation page like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(){/*Your js here*/} 

</script>
```